# Frisby.jsでネストしたJSON ResponseのテストにCustom Matcherが使えない

Tags: javascript, rest, テスト

REST APIのテストフレームワークであるFrisby.jsに関する質問。
レスポンスのJSONデータの値が「nullか文字列」である事をテストしたい場合、以下のような形でCustom Matcherが使える。

```
frisby.create('Test using a path as the paramater')
.get('http://localhost:3000/test')
.expectJSONTypes('member.*', {
    "name": String,
    "hobby": function(val) { expect(val).toBeTypeOrNull(String); }, // Custom Matcher
    "rank": {
        "name": string, 
        "point": Number
    }
})
.toss()
```

しかし、JSONがネストしている場合、Custom Matcherがうまく使えない。
例えば"rank"の"name"がnullか文字列というテストをしようとするとエラーとなってしまう。
解決方法が分かれば教えて下さい。

```
frisby.create('Test using a path as the paramater')
.get('http://localhost:3000/test')
.expectJSONTypes('member.*', {
    "name": String,
    "hobby": String,
    "rank": {
        "name": function(val) { expect(val).toBeTypeOrNull(String); }, // エラーになる 
        "point": Number
    }
})
.toss()
```

エラーメッセージは以下。

```
1) Frisby Test: Test using a path as the paramater 
    [ GET http://localhost:3000/test ]
 Message:
   Error: Expected 'string' to be type 'object' on key 'name'
 Stacktrace:
   Error: Expected 'string' to be type 'object' on key 'name'
  at _jsonContainsTypes (/home/vagrant/frisby_test/node_modules/frisby/lib/frisby.js:1283:15)
  at _jsonContainsTypes (/home/vagrant/frisby_test/node_modules/frisby/lib/frisby.js:1271:9)
  at jasmine.Matchers.toContainJsonTypes (/home/vagrant/frisby_test/node_modules/frisby/lib/frisby.js:1156:12)
  at /home/vagrant/frisby_test/node_modules/frisby/lib/frisby.js:573:22
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/vagrant/frisby_test/node_modules/frisby/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:81:11)
  at null.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/frisby_test/node_modules/frisby/lib/frisby.js:572:9)
  at null.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/frisby_test/node_modules/frisby/lib/frisby.js:1043:43)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.expectJsonTypes()`は内部的にはJasmineのカスタムmatcherを呼んでいる](https://github.com/vlucas/frisby/blob/3b5f4146ff919a7687ed83501a2deef06d3f2282/lib/frisby.js#L1186)ので、それを利用して最上位の `"key": object` に対してCustom Matcherを書くことでわりときれいに回避できます:

```js
var frisby = require('frisby');
beforeEach(function() {
  this.addMatchers(jasmine.Matchers.prototype);
})
frisby.create('Test using a path as the paramater')
.get('http://localhost:3000/test')
.expectJSONTypes("members.*", {
    "name": String,
    "hobby": String,
    "rank": function(val) {
      expect(val).toContainJsonTypes({
        "name": function(val) {
          expect(val).toBeTypeOrNull(String);
        },
        "point": Number
      })
    }
})
.toss()
```

`beforeEach` は、ちょっと処理内容が冗長になりますが、Frisbyが内部で定義しているカスタムmatcherが正しくJasmineに登録されていなかったため追加しました。これを追加しない場合、`expect`の結果を`return`し、Frisbyにテストの成否を判定させる必要があります。

なお、この「ネストされたオブジェクトにカスタムmatcherが使えない」問題に関して[バグ報告](https://github.com/vlucas/frisby/issues/93)が[上がっています](https://github.com/vlucas/frisby/issues/93)。修正されれば不要な回避策になります。